# How to build Stateful "Action Icons" in flutter appBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android, flutter-appbar

I'm a new learner of flutter, and I meet a problem when I create my appBar for Android apps.
There should be a button of the "camera flashlight" icon on the action area of appBar, and users can tap on this icon to choose flashlight options (on/off/auto) from a popupmenu, I finished this step.

But if I want the flashlight icon on the action area of appBar changes with the change of users' choice (e.g. if the user chooses auto, then the appBar icon should display an"auto flashlight"), how should I achieve it?

Thank you so much in advance.

I had tried using an "if" in the appBar action icon widget, and it failed.

Now my code in appBar.dart is

```
`Icon flashIcon = Icon(Icons.flash_auto);
FlashMode flashstate;

setIcon([Icon Function() param0]) {
  if (flashstate == FlashMode.off) {
    setIcon(() => flashIcon = Icon(Icons.flash_off));
  } else if (flashstate == FlashMode.torch) {
    flashIcon = Icon(Icons.flash_on);
  } else if (flashstate == FlashMode.always) {
    flashIcon = Icon(Icons.flash_on);
  } else {
    flashIcon = Icon(Icons.flash_auto);
  }
}`
```

and for the Action button codes is：`

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
              icon: setIcon(),

              onSelected: widget.isFlash,
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                List<PopupMenuEntry<String>> menuEntries2 = [
                  const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.flash_auto,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    value: 'auto',
                  ),
                  const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    child: Icon(Icons.flash_off, color: Colors.black),
                    value: 'off',
                  ),
                  const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    child: Icon(Icons.flash_on, color: Colors.black),
                    value: 'torch',
                  ),
                ];
                return menuEntries2;
              },
            ),`
```

But the issue is still not resolved...The icon becomes three dots, and if I choose flashlight status in the popup menu, nothing change.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyTRo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LoyC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Icons are widgets. You can render widgets conditionally using [stateful widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try code below and you got the exact output which is you describe

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code:-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OptionMenuExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const OptionMenuExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OptionMenuExample> createState() => _OptionMenuExampleState();
}

class _OptionMenuExampleState extends State<OptionMenuExample> {
  int selectedValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Appbar"),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            initialValue: selectedValue,
            onSelected: (int value) => setState(() {
              selectedValue = value;
            }),
            child: Icon(
                selectedValue == 1
                    ? Icons.flash_off
                    : selectedValue == 2
                        ? Icons.flash_auto
                        : Icons.flash_on,
                color: Colors.black),
            itemBuilder: (context) => const [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Icon(Icons.flash_on, color: Colors.black),
                value: 0,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Icon(Icons.flash_off, color: Colors.black),
                value: 1,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Icon(Icons.flash_auto, color: Colors.black),
                value: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 16.0)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! It works now. Could I also wonder why I cant not use "switch case" or "if else" to change the state in flutter? Is there a rule or something like that?

Comment: You can use switch case and if conditions both, but when you update the icon via pressing the button that time use setState method for rebuild thats it.

Comment: I had accepted it but I need more reputation to vote. Although the UI improved with your advice, I may need to think about how to connect the button to the function in main.dart. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code, here is my suggestion. You can write a code like this:

```
Icon icon = Icon(Icons./*icon name*/);
```

And then create a function like:

```
setIcon() {
   //here you use the value of your popup(or whatever you are using to let the user choose the state of flash) to change icon
   //example 
   if(value == **condition**) {
       setState(() => icon = /*new icon*/);
   } else {...} //and so on for all conditions 
   //or use a switch case if you prefer 
}
```

Now you call the function in the callback of your popup(or whatever) and use variable `icon` in your appBar button.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment first! But I had tried your advice and the issue is still there. I had attached the code above, and Im a little bit confused now. If you got time, could you have a look or share more hints? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't used my example really well, there are differences between the codes, but you can just use @MohammedAli answer since it's working.